# Including DIV elements in Server Side Include Files

Tags: html, include, ssi

Is it a good practice to include DIV container elements in SSI files or should I only put the tags within the DIV container in it. For example in the code below I have a footer which appears under all pages. Should I put only the `<p>` and `<a>` elements in the SSI file or `<div>` elements as well?

```
<div id="footer">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div id="footer_content">
     <p>Copyright 2010 New Life e. V.<br />
         <a href="en/contact.htm">Contact</a> |
         <a href="en/map.htm">Find Us</a>   |
         <a href="en/impressum.htm">Impressum</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to put the whole footer DIV in the include file. Otherwise pages that don't need a footer will also have to carry the unnecessary outer DIVs.

Comment: Well, all pages will have a footer.

Comment: Ok, even in that case a) it is better to be future considerate (you *may* need footer less pages as your business expands) and b) it makes more sense to have all of the footer's markup in one place than distributed.